# Convert table from excel to latex with format $10^{-n}$

Tags: excel, excel2latex

I would like to convert a table from Mircosoft Excel to latex (on Winedt) based on Microsoft Windows operation system. The number in excel is, for instance,

---

1                 2

1.00E-02    1.05E-03

---

I would like to have 1.00 $\times 10^{-2}$ and 1.05$\times 10^{-3}$ in latex table directly.

I have tried excel2latex.xla, it could convert table, but does not change formatting as $\times 10^{-2}$. Is there any simple way to do that? though I am somehow doubt about it...

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to understand your question and suggest solutions when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. Since the conversion is not itself the issue, I suggest creating a minimal document containing a small table illustrating the formatting you get from conversion.

Comment: It may be important to know which OS you are using and which editor. On GNU/Linux, OS X or similar Unix-like systems, regular expressions can easily do what you want. I believe that WinEdit has support for this on Windows but don't know the details.

Comment: Thanks for your instructions. I have tried to add a few details of the problem, and specify the OS I am using. Since it is rather a general problem of converting from excel to latex, I am not sure how to create a MWE..

Comment: If your editor supports regular expressions, I can post a regular expression search and replace code that works with `WinEdt`. However there some differences between GNU regular expressions and WinEdt regular expressions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The package [`siunitx`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/siunitx) could be a solution for you, but it requires some adjustment of the `excel2latex` output, which I'll explain below. `siunitx` defines a special column type, `S` used in place of the usual `l`,`c`,`r` specifications.

Each cell entry is then taken as the argument to `siunitx`'s `\num{}` command, which accepts scientific notation input as 1.00E-02.

One behavior of this solution is that `siunitx` centers the columns around the decimal separator. `siunitx` tries to be smart about what is text/headings and what is numerical data. But anything that could be mistaken for numerical data (in your example, the first row, which I'm assuming contains headings) should be protected with curly braces.

So, to apply this solution to `excel2latex` output, you'll have to:

1. load the `siunitx` package in the document preamble,
2. change column specifiers from `c` (or `l` or `r`) to `s` in the beginning of the `tabular` environment for any columns with numerical data, and
3. protect any non-numerical data that shouldn't be aligned at the decimal separator with curly braces `{}`.

An example:

### Before:

```
\begin{tabular}{cc}
1 & 2 \\
1.00E-02 & 1.05E-03 \\
\end{tabular}
```

### After:

```
\begin{tabular}{SS}
{1} & {2} \\
1.00E-02 & 1.05E-03 \\
\end{tabular}
```

### Complete Code and Output:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{SS}
{1} & {2} \\
1.00E-02 & 1.05E-03 \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Many adjustments can be made for alignment and spacing of the `S` columns. If you decide this solution is workable for you, you can consult the [package manual](http://www.texdoc.net/pkg/siunitx) (Section 4.6) for details.

Answer (score 2):

The literal answer likely requires a bit of formula writing in Excel. Given a numeric value 1.05E-3 in cell B2, you can extract the mantissa and exponent with the following formulas (via [getting the exponent and mantissa from scientific format at Mr. Excel](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/58378-getting-exponent-mantissa-scientific-format.html)):

- Exponent (cell F2): `=INT(LOG(B2))`
- Mantissa (cell E2): `=B2/10^F2`
- Formatted text version (cell I2): `="$"&TEXT(E2,"0.00")&"\times 10^{"&F2&"}$"`

But here’s a much simpler alternative answer using the [`siunitx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/siunitx) package and its S column type (section 4.6):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{SS}
1.00E-02 & 1.05E-03
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]